# Hide VBA codes when double clicking controls buttons

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have inserted a combo box on PPT slide. When I double click the combo box, the VBA editing window will pop up. Is there a way that when I double click the box, VBA code does not pop up? I don't want users to see my actual codes and VBA window in general.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your users will be viewing the presentation in slideshow view, doubleclicking won't open the VBA editor.  If you don't need them to be able to edit the presentation, save it as a PowerPoint Macro-enabled Show (ie, a PPSM) and distribute that. When doubleclicked, the file will open directly into slideshow view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have design mode on. Have a look under Developer > Controls > Design Mode. Turning it off should remove that behaviour.